# Command or steps to list out the callstack of other threads where a particular pointer is used?

Tags: multithreading, windbg, callstack

I am new to using Windbg. I got a crash dump of my application. Using Windbg I could able to get the callstack of crash and found that dynamic_cast is failing for a pointer. Since pointer is corrupted already, dynamic_cast is failing.

Now I am not sure how this pointer get corrupted. It may be from  another thread. How can I found out the callstack of other threads where the same pointer is corrupted.

or

Call stack of other threads where the corrupted pointer is used. So that I should analyze the reason for the corrupted pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the call stacks of all threads:

```
~* kb
```

and then scan the call stacks for the address of your pointer assuming that another thread was trying to access it, when I say scan this means simple search using <kbd>f3</kbd>.

Additionally if you have lots of worker threads then `!uniqstack` will just list the unique call stacks and list the thread ids that have that call stack. Remember when you want to look at other threads you need to *switch* threads by calling `~#s` there is more info on the syntax [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).